# Exporting raster data from QGIS in chosen projection

Tags: qgis, raster, export

**EDIT: it is seeming like some of the time my last method will lead to a correct projection, some of the time it will not.  Unsure what's happening there but at least trial and error will get me through what I'm doing now.  Any suggestions for a more robust method would be appreciated.**

apologies if this has been answered somewhere, but I've not found a solution I could get working.

I have a DEM file that I need to change the projection of, and then export for use in another program (accepts gdal).  I am using QGIS.  I can import it to QGIS and change the projection no problem, but cannot figure out how to export the result for rasters (fine for vectors).

I have tried using the clipper to save a copy, however this changes the projection to WGS84, defeating the purpose.  I have set the project to my projection of choice AGD66, and in Settings/Options have set all options to this projection.  The clipper always converts to EPSG:4326 - WGS 84. I have tried both with and without on the fly reprojections.

I have tried to use the GRASS plugin and use r.out.gdal.gtiff and r.out.gdal, however output files are all blank.

Through the Sextante toolbox I have tried GDAL Conversion/Translate however this too puts everything in EPSG:4326 - WGS 84.  The option "Override the projection for the output file" with AGD66 selected led to the error

---

An error has occured while executing Python code:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/.../.qgis//python/plugins\sextante\gui\CrsSelectionDialog.py", line 47, in okPressed
    self.authid = self.selector.selectedAuthId()
AttributeError: 'QgsProjectionSelector' object has no attribute 'selectedAuthId'

Python version:
2.7.2 (default, Jun 12 2011, 15:08:59) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)]

QGIS version:
1.8.0-Lisboa Lisboa, f440b60

Python path: ['C:/Users/.../.qgis//python/plugins\sextante', 'C:/PROGRA~2/Quantum GIS Lisboa/apps/qgis/./python', 'C:/Users/.../.qgis//python', 'C:/Users/.../.qgis//python/plugins', 'C:/PROGRA~2/Quantum GIS Lisboa/apps/qgis/./python/plugins', 'C:\PROGRA~2\Quantum GIS Lisboa\bin\python27.zip', 'C:\PROGRA~2\Quantum GIS Lisboa\apps\Python27\DLLs', 'C:\PROGRA~2\Quantum GIS Lisboa\apps\Python27\lib', 'C:\PROGRA~2\Quantum GIS Lisboa\apps\Python27\lib\plat-win', 'C:\PROGRA~2\Quantum GIS Lisboa\apps\Python27\lib\lib-tk', 'C:\PROGRA~2\Quantum GIS Lisboa\apps\qgis\bin', 'C:\PROGRA~2\Quantum GIS Lisboa\apps\Python27', 'C:\PROGRA~2\Quantum GIS Lisboa\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages', 'C:\PROGRA~2\Quantum GIS Lisboa\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\PIL', 'C:\PROGRA~2\Quantum GIS Lisboa\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32', 'C:\PROGRA~2\Quantum GIS Lisboa\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32\lib', 'C:\PROGRA~2\Quantum GIS Lisboa\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\Pythonwin', 'C:\PROGRA~2\Quantum GIS Lisboa\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\wx-2.8-msw-unicode', 'C:\PROGRA~2\Quantum GIS Lisboa\apps\qgis\python\plugins\fTools\tools']

---

I thought I had a solution using Raster/Converstion/Translate (convert format) as this runs and lets me set the Target SRS, however the output is still EPSG:4326 - WGS 84.  I do get the following error

---

Warning 6: A dataset opened by GDALOpenShared should have the same filename (C:\Users...\demh\w001001x.adf) and description (C:...\demh)

---

Any suggestions for how I can get raster data OUT of QGIS would be very much appreciated.  Or - if you can't get data out of QGIS, can you suggest an alternative free GIS system that works nicely with projections?  I have tried SAGA, however have not had much luck getting reprojections to work properly.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In QGIS, `Raster -> projections -> warp` calling GDAL's gdalwarp utility is the method to change the CRS of a raster file.

This is an external command, so it does not look at the **project** or **layer** CRS you might have set in QGIS.

Select the right CRS for source, and the desired for target CRS, abd give the output a different filename. You can add the result to the canvas, and check the extent in the layers properties, metadata tab. It should be different from the originals extent

Comment: Thankyou very much for the help Andre, much appreciated.  This looks to also have solved another problem I had with area calculations going wrong.  Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

Since QGIS 2.0 will be out soon, I think it's necessary to mention that in 2.0 raster layers also have a "Save as ..." option - just like vector layers - which will make things much easier.